# Trying to find a proper context for drawing a UIImage in a UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am trying to draw a background image in my UIView. This is in a UIAlertView delegate method alertView:
I pop the context because before this I was using a context in a OpenGL view called game.

```
UIGraphicsPopContext();
UIImage* background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];
[background drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];

// fade the game out
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[game setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[game release];
```

I get a bunch of error messages such as : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context
I tried it without popping.
I guess what I need to do is find my UIView's CGContextRef, and set that as my current context, but the documentation contains no info regarding CGContextRef.
How can I display my image? I am trying to show the image behind the game view while it fades out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. All I had to do was put the UIImage in a UIImageView, and add it to the subview of my view.

Answer (score 1):

@hyn is right!
To give an example:

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"38-airplane.png"]];
```